# Two node.js processes are running while I don't suppose that. Can I kill them?

Tags: node.js, pm2

While I don't suppose that there are any processes for node.js on my windows computer, but there are two node.js processes that I can see on task manager.

[image]

I don't mean to run any node.js right now. But I have two node.js processes like above.

I had run node.js process by `pm2` module before, so it affects badly maybe.

Is it ok to kill the two processes manually from task manager? Or, either process has any other purposes than executing program I wrote, so I should keep either of them or both?

Comment: Since you are saying task manager, I am assuming windows. Yes I would assume that it is ok

Comment: thanks. ok, I will kill the node.js processes.